# Rails, Ffmpeg, & Heroku: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - the ffprobe binary could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg

I'm using the streamio-ffmpeg rails gem and it works fine on my local machine. But when trying to run it on Heroku, I get the below error:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - the ffprobe binary could
>   not be found in
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/streamio-ffmpeg-2.0.0/lib/streamio-ffmpeg.rb:87

What does this mean?

Comment: Is the `ffprobe` binary in any of those paths shown in your Heroku error output?

Comment: No, it's not. I thought the gem would take care of it. How do I add the ffprobe binary?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is pretty simple - just needed to add an Ffmpeg buildpack to my project:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git

https://github.com/HYPERHYPER/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg